# WP_Query based on meta data boolean

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, meta

In my wordpress site I have created a meta box for any page which is using post.php
This meta box includes a boolean checkbox where I want to decide whether or not it's going to be included with a WP_Query.
When _is_private page is true I wan't to remove the post from search

Only problem is I can't get the expected result.
See below for my code.

```
$meta_query = array(
      'key' => '_is_private_page',
      'value' => 'true',
      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
  );


$wp_query_args = array(
    's' => $_GET['s'],
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
);


$query = new WP_Query( $wp_query_args );
```

Comment: Could you also provide a var_dump() of your results in your question

Comment: Does the Query convert it into sql. If so you could use '<>' instead of NOT EXISTS. Also does the Query convert the true to all different booleans. I've seen instances when the string 'on' and '1' have been stored in the meta table instead of 'true'

Answer (score 1):

You need to select all posts/pages that *not* private, so they will have meta value not equal *true*

```
$meta_query = array(
      'key' => '_is_private_page',
      'value' => 'true',
      'compare' => '!=',
  );
$wp_query_args = array(
    's' => $_GET['s'],
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
);


$query = new WP_Query( $wp_query_args );
```

To select all that have meta value not equal to true or have no meta:

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => '_is_private_page',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
      ),
    array(
        'key' => '_is_private_page',
        'value' => 'true',
        'compare' => '!=',
      ),
);

$wp_query_args = array(
    's' => $_GET['s'],
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
);

$query = new WP_Query( $wp_query_args );
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have a feeling it's something to do with that when the value is unset

Comment: I've changed answer. Have a look second snippet